# Unsupported GPT detected. Use GNU Parted

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, gpt, android-x86

I'm installing Android-x86 in Dell XPS on SSD disk.
I use GPT on SSD disk as follows with using gparted.

```
$ sudo parted -l /dev/sdb

Model: ATA SAMSUNG SSD CM85 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  32.0GB  32.0GB  ext4
```

But, if I try to install Android-x86 on this disk, the installer says:

```
Warning!!   Unsupported GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected. Use GNU Parted.
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what installer program you're trying to use, but apparently it doesn't support GPT...

If you use a MBR on the disk, and try it again it might work. I don't see how a 32GB disk would be worse using MBR, there couldn't be any partitions bigger than 2TB.